# Use input in mysql_query

Tags: mysql, validation, input

I have a problem with using a input that I get form my first page. I want to use it to check if there are enough credits to play a game. To be complete, I have one page with a range slider.

```html
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
<input type="range" name="myrange" id="myrange" class="myrange" min="0" max="5" value="0" step="0.10" data-popup-enabled="true"> 
</form>
```

On my second page called VALIDATE.PHP I get the post action. I have setup the following:

```html
if ($check['credits']<=0.10) { echo header ('Location: validate.php?nocredits'); }
else { mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = (credits -0.10) WHERE username='".$_SESSION['login']."'");
```

I am trying to make the values 0.10 and -0.10 in my validate.php dynamic. To be more exact I want to use the input of the range. So that the value 0.10 is depended from the range input. I am sure this is possible within PHP, but I am really stuck at this point and can't find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: only `name` and `value` attributes of input elements are passed to server side. you can't directly read `min` or `max` or `step` from `myrange`

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.I am just a beginner, but I think I understand what you mean. So I should get something like this:

$myrange = $_POST['myrange'];
if ($check['credits']<=($_POST['myrange'])) { echo header ('Location: validate.php?status=nocredits'); }
else { mysql_query("UPDATE users SET credits = (credits -'{$_POST[myrange]}') WHERE username='".$_SESSION['login']."'"); }

Comment: yes, exactly.with `$_POST['myrange'];`, you will get the `value` of `myrange`. i actually thought that you wish to fetch `min, max, step` values. obviously i was mistaken:]

Comment: It was not your mistake, I was bad in my underpinning. 
Thanks for the feedback, I'll give it a try :)